# PDFium limited javascript support

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdfium

I would like to use the built-in JavaScript for PDFium. I know PDFium has limited JavaScript support but I have seen posts that it does have [a few available commands](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/pdf/instance.cc).

Here is what I'd like to do, when the pdf is opened (in PDFium), I'd like to have it automatically open to the last page and remove the print button. These are both available commands using the PDFium source, but I haven't seen any documentation/examples on how to use them.

I am assuming I can embed these commands into the PDF itself but I'm at a loss as to how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Available parameters I found are only few: [Adobe parameters](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf#page=5)

A possible workaround for the last page is to set the parameter `#page=100000` to 100000 for example.